# ¿Como se valida que un vector no pueda repetir letras en c++?

Tags: c++

He estado tratando de hacer una validación que al ingresar letras en un vector no permita repeticiones de las letras, por ejemplo ingreso la letra "a" y la vuelvo a ingresar deberia de aparecerme que ya ha sido ingresada pero no lo logro hacer... Este es el código que tengo espero que alguien me pueda ayudar!!!

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "stdio.h"

using namespace std;

void noRepetir();

int main()
{
    int opc = 0;
    do {
        noRepetir();
        cout << "Ingresar otro dato? (1 = Si | 0 = No) ";
        cin >> opc;
    } while (opc == 1);

    return 0;
}

void noRepetir() {

    char vector[20];
    char letra;

    cout << "Ingrese la letra: ";
    cin >> letra;
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {

        if (letra != vector[i]) {
            vector[i] = letra;
        }
        else {
            cout << "Esta letra ya ha sido ingrasada " << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Vamos a centrarnos en la pieza central de tu algoritmo:

```
cout << "Ingrese la letra: ";
cin >> letra;
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {

    if (letra != vector[i]) {
        vector[i] = letra;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Esta letra ya ha sido ingrasada " << endl;
    }
}
```

**1er error**

Imagínate que es la primera letra que se introduce... el algoritmo la comparará con las 20 posiciones que tiene el array... ¿Y qué hay en esas posiciones del array? dado que no lo has inicializado, basura... así que una posibilidad podría ser:

```
df!f20y43%_SD435?a.{
```

Fíjate que en las últimas posiciones hay una `a`:

```
df!f20y43%_SD435?a.{
                 ^
```

Así que el algoritmo te dirá que la letra está repetida pese a que es la primera letra que se ingresa...

La solución a este problema es tan sencilla como incializar `vector` antes de introducir una palabra:

```
std::fill(vector,vector+20,'0');
```

O también puedes inicializar el vector al declararlo:

```
char vector[TamVector] = {'\0'};
```

Aunque a mi personalmente no me hace mucha gracia tener ese `20` pululando por el código... si luego tengo que cambiar el tamaño del array me toca buscar ese `20` por todo el código para evitar errores. Sería mejor tener algo así:

```
const int TamVector = 20;
char vector[TamVector];

// ...

for( int i=0; i<TamVector; i++ )
// ...
```

**2º error**

> y la vuelvo a ingresar deberia de aparecerme que ya ha sido ingresada pero no lo logro hacer...

Si te fijas, verás que `vector` es una variable local de `noRepetir`. Lo que hace `noRepetir` es leer una única letra y buscarla en `vector`, tras lo cual devuelve el control a `main`. Cuando esto sucede el contenido de `vector` se pierde, ya que la variable se destruye... Dado que la idea es que el array sea algo más persistente quizás debieras declararlo en `main`:

```
const int TamVector = 20;

int main()
{
  char vector[TamVector] = {'\0'};

  noRepetir(vector, TamVector);
}

void noRepetir(char *vector, int tamVector)
{
  // ...
}
```

Con esto conseguirás que la información que almacenes en `vector` sea persistente entre llamadas a `noRepetir`... pero el programa seguirá sin funcionar...

... y el motivo es la línea que destaco:

```
if (letra != vector[i]) {
    vector[i] = letra; // <<---
}
```

¿Por qué es problemática esa línea?

Veamos... el usuario introduce una letra y el algoritmo la compara con las 20 posiciones de `vector`. Si la letra no es igual a la almacenada en el vector... **sobreescribe** la letra almacenada en el vector con la letra que ha introducido el usuario.

Es decir, si asumimos que inicializas `vector` y que es la primera letra que introduce el usuario, después de llamar a `noRepetir` el vector quedará así (supongamos que el usuario introduce `a`):

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

Si después introduce una `x`:

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Visto lo visto no parece una buena idea que el algoritmo machaque posiciones de `vector` así a la ligera.

Lo que tienes que hacer es modificar el bucle para que itere desde 0 hasta que se encuentre una posición del vector no inicializada `vector[i]=='\0'` y, si la letra introducida por el usuario no se encuentra en `vector`, añadirla **únicamente** en la primera posición disponible. Algo así:

```
int i; // Ahora es necesario que `i` esté fuera del bucle
bool unica = true;

// Primero comprobamos que la letra no se ha introducido aun
for( i=0; i<tamVector && vector[i] != '\0' && unica; i++ )
  unica = (vector[i] == letra);

// Y despues, si no esta repetida, la añadimos al array
if( unica )
{
  if( i < tamVector ) // Importante para no escribir fuera del array
    vector[i] = letra; // antes de esta linea vector[i]=='\0'
}
else
{
  std::cout << "Esta letra ya ha sido ingrasada\n";
}
```

El programa, con las correspondientes correcciones:

```
#include <iostream>

void noRepetir(char * vector, int tamVector);

int main()
{
  int const TamVector = 20;
  char vector[TamVector] = {'\0'};

  int opc = 0;
  do {
    noRepetir(vector,TamVector);
    std::cout << "Ingresar otro dato? (1 = Si | 0 = No) ";
    std::cin >> opc;
  } while (opc == 1);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void noRepetir(char * vector, int tamVector)
{
  char letra;
  std::cout << "Ingrese la letra: ";
  std::cin >> letra;

  int i;
  bool unica = true;
  for( i=0; i<tamVector && vector[i] != '\0' && unica; i++ )
    unica = (vector[i] != letra);

  if( unica )
  {
    if( i < tamVector )
      vector[i] = letra;
  }
  else
  {
    std::cout << "Esta letra ya ha sido ingrasada\n";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A parte de la excelente respuesta de [eferion](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/133620/2742), quería sugerirte el uso de las [librerías STL de C++](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/STL) para tu código, en concreto las cabeceras [`<string>`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string) y [`<algorithm>`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm).

Tu `char vector[20];` puede ser substituido por un `std::string` y toda tu función `noRepetir` puede ser una llamada a [`std::count`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count). Así pues tu código sería, sencillamente:

```
int opc = 0;
std::string letras;

do {
    int letra;
    std::cout << "Ingrese la letra: ";
    std::cin >> letra;

    if (std::count(letras.begin(), letras.end(), letra))
        std::cout << "Esta letra ya ha sido ingrasada\n";
    else
        letras.push_back(letra);

    std::cout << "Ingresar otro dato? (1 = Si | 0 = No) ";
    std::cin >> opc;
    std::cout << letras << '\n';

} while (opc == 1);
```

La función `std::count` cuenta cuántas veces aparece el tercer parámetro entre los iteradores pasados como primer y segundo parámetro; por lo tanto si devuelve algo diferente de `0` significará que la *`letra ya ha sido ingresada`*.

Al utilizar un `std::string` en lugar de una formación <sup>1</sup> no debes preocuparte de controlar la posición en que escribir pues puedes ir acumulando datos mediante `std::string::push_back`.

---

<sup>1</sup>O arreglo, también conocida como array en inglés.

Answer (score 1):

Esto funciona:

```
#include "iostream"
#include "stdio.h"

using namespace std;

// noRepetir() ya toma dos argumentos, el vector donde guardo las letras y el numero de letras que llevo agregadas
int noRepetir(char arg_vector[], int arg_cont_letras);

int main()
{
    int opc = 0;
    char my_vector[20];
    // cont_letras cuenta el numero de letras que llevo
    // en el vector para saber en que indice agregarla
    int cont_letras = 0;
    do {
        // mi funcion noRepetir devuelve 0 en caso de que la letra este repetida
        // aca verifico si la letra se agrego para aumentar el numero de letras agregadas (cont_letras)
        if (noRepetir(my_vector, cont_letras) != 0){
            cont_letras++;
        }
        cout << "Ingresar otro dato? (1 = Si | 0 = No) ";
        cin >> opc;
    } while (opc == 1);

    return 0;
}

int noRepetir(char arg_vector[], int arg_cont_letras) {
    char letra;

    cout << "Ingrese la letra: ";
    cin >> letra;
    // itero en el vector verificando si la letra ya fue almacenada
    for (int i = 0; i < arg_cont_letras; i++) {

        if (letra != arg_vector[i]) {
            continue;
        }
        // si la letra ya esta almacenada devuelvo 0
        else {
            cout << "Esta letra ya ha sido ingrasada " << endl;
            return 0;
        }
    }
    // si el flujo de mi programa llego hasta aca quiere decir que la letra no esta almaceenada en el vector
    // almaceno la letra, aca entra el papel de saber cuantas letras llevo almacenadas para poder almacenarla
    // en ese indice del vector
    arg_vector[arg_cont_letras] = letra;
}
```

**Edito por la apreciación de @paula_plus_plus**

```
#include "iostream"
#include "stdio.h"

using namespace std;

// noRepetir() ya toma dos argumentos, el vector donde guardo las letras y el numero de letras que llevo agregadas
int noRepetir(char arg_vector[], int arg_cont_letras);

int main()
{
    int opc = 0;
    // inicializo el vector como buena practica, sin embargo
    // esto no afecta el funcionamiento del algoritmo
    char my_vector[20] = {'\0'};
    // cont_letras cuenta el numero de letras que llevo
    // en el vector para saber en que indice agregarla
    int cont_letras = 0;
    do {
        // mi funcion noRepetir devuelve 0 en caso de que la letra este repetida
        // aca verifico si la letra se agrego para aumentar el numero de letras agregadas (cont_letras)
        if (noRepetir(my_vector, cont_letras) != 0){
            cont_letras++;
        }
        cout << "Ingresar otro dato? (1 = Si | 0 = No) ";
        cin >> opc;
    } while (opc == 1);

    return 0;
}

int noRepetir(char arg_vector[], int arg_cont_letras) {
    char letra;

    cout << "Ingrese la letra: ";
    cin >> letra;
    // itero en el vector verificando si la letra ya fue almacenada
    for (int i = 0; i < arg_cont_letras; i++) {

        if (letra != arg_vector[i]) {
            continue;
        }
        // si la letra ya esta almacenada devuelvo 0
        else {
            cout << "Esta letra ya ha sido ingrasada " << endl;
            return 0;
        }
    }
    // si el flujo de mi programa llego hasta aca quiere decir que la letra no esta almaceenada en el vector
    // almaceno la letra, aca entra el papel de saber cuantas letras llevo almacenadas para poder almacenarla
    // en ese indice del vector
    arg_vector[arg_cont_letras] = letra;
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias por el aporte! empezare a leer el codigo para entenderlo al 100

Comment: "*Esto funciona*" de casualidad, como ha dicho [eferion](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/133620/2742), se está utilizando `my_vector` sin inicializar, así que podría contener (casualmente) la letra buscada. Para solucionarlo declara `my_vector` así: `char my_vector[20]{};`. Por otro lado, podrías pasar el vector por referencia a `noRepetir`: `int noRepetir(char (&arg_vector)[20], const int arg_cont_letras)`.

Comment: Hola @Paula_plus_plus si bien es una buena practica inicializar el vector, se me ha pasado y ya editaré la respuesta. Sin embargo, el código no funciona de casualidad como dices ya que es controlada la iteración del bucle en el vector con el numero de letras que ha ingresado el usuario. La primera vez que se ingresa una letra el vector no se recorre porque no se cumple la condición para que el bucle itere y luego el vector es recorrido solo en los espacios que ya han sido ocupados y no en espacios que contengan basura. Saludos!

Comment: ¡Tienes razón! No caí en que en la primera llamada `arg_cont_letras` es `0`.